# Unity Animator Doesn't show game objects on device but plays in editor

Tags: animator, unity-game-engine

I have following scenario.
Parent gameobject has animator which rotate in y dir from pt A to pt B.
And the child gameObject has script which moves or rotate child object from pt C to d. When I play these scene in Unity editor it works perfectly and gives proper output. But when I run same Scene on Device the parent object is invisible. I also checked its runtime position, Its same as Default(Original). So there is no problem of position also. So why parent gameObject is invisible on Devices.

Comment: which platform are you developing for? there may be a number of reasons. I think animation has nothing to do with this (from all the info you provided). If you think it's an animation issue, have you tried to remove the Animation/Animator component for testing?. It may as well be a shader issue, if you are using a custom shader test using standard Unity shader. It may be an occlusion issue, if you are deforming geometry and not calling `Mesh.RecalculateBounds()` the camera may not render your mesh (thinking it's not in camera spectrum).

Comment: Also, are there any exceptions logged when you test on your device? Are you sure you're not using preprocessor directives like `#if UNITY_EDITOR` ?